# Cocoa path string conversion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to convert /Users/Irwan/Documents/test.jpg into MyMac:Users:Irwan:Documents:test.jpg
I can do that manually but I wonder if there is easy way to do it ?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to generate the colon-separated path for? I don't believe it's used by any modern APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
path = (NSString *)CFURLCopyFileSystemPath((CFURLRef)url, kCFURLHFSPathStyle);
[path autorelease];
```

Comment: Ooo, nice. I looked at `CFString` and found nothing; should’ve looked at `CFURL`, too.